# Mapping through objects and display images dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, object, expo, maps

I have a state that is holding an object with the following.  Each is an object with that holds the following data

```
base64: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACGwAABBACAYAAAAiFe8LAAABd
height: 4160
uri: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2124B18A-AD51-4720-9D7E-7DB51C468579/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540arod1207%252FAOS/ImageManipulator/FC7FBA31-D7F8-4EC2-ABA2-7CA8DC9F8D46.png"
width: 2156
```

I am trying to map over the object and display the base64 image dynamically

I don't know how to access just the base64 key and place it for example.

```
<td>
  <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${pictureImage.base64}"
    style="width: 40vw;" />
</td>
```

I know that you can't map over an object, so I have also tried something similar to this

```
const res = Object.keys(allImages).reduce( (res, key) => {
  res[key] = allImages[key].value
  return res;
}, {});
```

I just need the base64 data and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your state right then try this:

```
const App = () => {
    const state = {
        key1: { base64: "1" },
        key2: { base64: "2" }
    };

    return Object.entries(state).map(([key, value]) => {
        return (
            <td key={key}>
                <img
                    src={`data:image/jpg;base64,${value.base64}`}
                    style="width: 40vw;"
                />
            </td>
        );
    });
};
```